# CLI command in Java 11: Running a class vs running a module

Tags: java, command-line, java-11, java-module

I am preparing for a Java 11 certification exam and I still do not fully understand the new Java modules system: A training question gives a situation like the following:
In my app I have 2 jars, say `A.jar` and `B.jar`, where `A.jar` uses `B.jar`, but `B.jar` does not use `A.jar`.
Further, `B.jar` is modularized, while `A.jar` is not.

Now it sais, that if I try to run it like this:

```
java -classpath A.jar --module-path B.jar com.AMainClass
```

with a main class from A.jar, then it will fail to run - but why? For what I understood, when I put a non-modularized jar on the classpath, it becomes part of the "unnamed module", which should be able to see all the modules on the module path. So shouldn´t I be able to see the required dependencies from B.jar, when I run the main class from A.jar? Where is my misunderstanding?

It further sais, that it will work, if I put both jars on the module path and run the module instead of running the class:

```
java --module-path A.jar;B.jar --module A/com.AMainClass
```

Now `A.jar`, being on the module path, will become an automatic module and will also see the other module - ok, this is fine. But what is the difference between running a module and running a class? Why doesn´t it work when I try to run the class (as above) and what changes, when I run the module?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected the question.

Comment: But are you sure about the details of the training question? If it is the other way round, B uses A, it’s clear that A must become an automatic module to satisfy a `requires A;` directive in `B`’s declaration. The scenario of A being non-modular but using other modular code, is what we have every day when running old software on newer JDKs, as the old software is non-modular but the JDK classes are modular.